# javascript onchange in php while loop

Tags: php, javascript, forms, onload

I have a form where radio types are generated inside a PHP while loop.  Depending on which radio is selected, java script queries MySQL to get the correct value and return it to a text box.  It works except for onload.  OnLoad returns the incorrect value, whatever was first in the while loop iteration.  Onchange will return the right value.

How can I get onload to return the right value?  I am using "checked" in my radio throughout the while iteration so that one circle is always checked.  It doesn't matter to me which radio is checked by default.  Using checked in the while iteration always makes the last iteration checked which is OK, but it is displaying the value for the first.

here is my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getNextcheck(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("nextcheck").innerHTML="";
return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("nextcheck").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getnextcheck.php?id="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
window.onload = function() {
document.getElementsByName('ID')[0].onchange();
}


</script>
```

And the file getnextcheck.php it pulls

```
<?php
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/connect.php";


$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bankaccount WHERE ID = '$_GET[id]'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$nextcheck = $row['next_check'];

if (empty($nextcheck)) { $nextcheck = 0; }

echo "<tr><td>Check Number <input type=\"text\" name=\"checkno\" value=\"".$nextcheck."\" /></td></tr>";
```

And the radio inside the form.

```
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
$id = $row2['ID'];

echo "<tr><td><input type=\"radio\" name=\"ID\" value=\"".$row2['ID']."\" onchange=\"getNextcheck(this.value)\" checked></td><td>".$row2['name']."</td><td>".$row2['acctnum']."</td>";
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make only first radio check

```
<?
$i=0;
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
$id = $row2['ID'];
$checked = $i?'':'checked'; 
echo "<tr><td><input type=\"radio\" name=\"ID\" value=\"".$row2['ID']."\" onchange=\"getNextcheck(this.value)\" {$checked}></td><td>".$row2['name']."</td><td>".$row2['acctnum']."</td>";
$i=1;
}
?>
```

Comment: hmmm only problem is the value of my radio box is not posting.  I'm using echo "<div id=\"nextcheck\"> </div>"; in my form.  Any ideas here?

Comment: Sorry, meant the value of my text box is not posting.

Comment: print_r($_POST),what u see

Comment: It's not posting.  I think the form doesn't see it since it is javascript.  The only thing the form sees is the div tags without anything inside of them.  Can you recommend something I can do in the javascript to get the value from checkno and post it?

Comment: window.onload / click radio > getNextcheck > xmlhttp.responseText ...check which part not work .

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  I think I need to add something to my javascript in order to capture the checkno value and post it but not sure where to look.

Comment: It turns out it was a simple tag out of order issue.  I had an opening table tag outside of the form tag, but the closing table tag was inside the form tag.  Viewing firefox page code actually caught this for me.